# printing complete stack trace of an exception in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to print complete stack trace of the exception thrown by my android code in android studio. For this I am using `exception.printStackTrace();` I have also tried to use `Log.e("",Log.getStackTraceString(exception));` and `Log.e("TAG", "Exception: ", e.printStackTrace());` but the exception is not being displayed on the console, and the console is showing this:
[image]

So how can I print complete stack trace of the exception on console in android studio?

Comment: `Log.e("TAG", "Exception: ", e)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify `.printStackTrace()`, you will be fine :

```
Log.e("TAG", "Exception: ", e);
```